Conditionally display the drop-down list of values of a variable based the branch name GitLab pipeline
The globalvariables: section of my .gitlab-ci.yml file has been constructed like below:
variables:
  HOST_NAME:
    description: Select a host name to deploy
    value: web-server-dev-01
    options:
      - web-server-dev-01
      - web-server-dev-02
      - web-server-dev-03
      - web-server-prod-01
      - web-server-prod-02
      - web-server-prod-03

Now, when I run the pipeline, the HOST_NAME variable shows the default value web-server-dev-01 and other 6 server names become available in the drop-down list of this variable, whichever branch I run from.
I'd like to make the values available like below:

When running from dev branch, the default value of the HOST_NAME should show web-server-dev-01 and drop-down should show the first 3 server names (ending with dev-xx).
When running from master branch, the default value of the HOST_NAME should show web-server-prod-01 and drop-down should show the last server names (ending with prod-xx).

Is it possible? If so, would you please show how?

You can configure a variable dependent on the branch like using rules:variables during the job run.
variables:
  SERVER_NO:
    description: Select a host name to deploy
    value: 01
    options:
      - 01
      - 02
      - 03

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to $HOSTNAME"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^dev$/
      variables:
        HOSTNAME: web-server-dev-$SERVER_NO
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^main$/
      variables:
        HOSTNAME: web-server-prod-$SERVER_NO


With this, the default value of HOST_NAME variable will show 01 and the drop-down list of of the values for this variable will show 01, 02, 03. This no way resolves my issue. If the question is not clear to you, please post in the comment, I will try to clarify.

The gitlab CI yaml spec doesn't support dynamic options in global variables where you show a different set of options depending on the run branch. You are only left with the option to provide a list of static options then use the selected option to generate the desired value for the job depending on the run branch.

Hi Oluwafemi Sule - My question was for finding a solution that can display dynamic options in global variables, based on the selected branch. So, the solution you provided doesn't resolve my issue.
